# Is there any way to guage what the id of an insert will be before inserting it?

Tags: php

Okay, I am allowing users to add products to my website, and I am storing the images like so:

> images/products/username/item*id*/filename.extension

which will look like:

> images/products/admin/item1/mypic.jpg

As you see, after the item, I am appending the item id from the database, so when the user is adding the images, it'll upload it to that folder and create that folder, is it possible to get the id of the next insert before it'been uploaded, or will I have to insert first, then use lastinsertid? What happens if the images fail to upload?

If that's not possible, how would I accomplish this

Comment: You can query for the highest `id` and then increment yourself. You would have to account for failure *prior* to insertion. No matter what you do you could encounter a race condition where two operations have gotten the same `'id` value. If one beats the other to the punch it could get ugly.

Comment: I think you will have to `INSERT` it first, the get `PDO::lastInsertId()`.

Comment: You can guess (and it's amazing how many people do) by getting the last id and adding 1, but you'll likely fail... in practise, that approach can only ever work on a system with a single user, and even then it's not foolproof

Comment: But in practise, add the entry to the database, get the last inserted id,  and only then create the folder and move the image.... if the images fail to upload, then youshould be testing for this before doing anything else anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments to your question, it's very problematic to query for what will likely be the next auto increment id in the database as it may not still be true by the time the insert query runs.

If you are wanting to ensure that if the upload fails you don't have records in the database for them I would suggest you use a [transactions](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.begintransaction.php).

This will basically allow you to run the query, get the last insert id, do whatever file upload/manipulation you need to do.  If that file upload or whatever fails, you can rollback the transaction which more or less undoes the insert, and you are back where you restarted.

If the file manipulation is successful, you commit the transaction and the inserts will actually be added to the database.